# Is there a way to view mail logs from mail() if you don't have .ini access (GoDaddy server)?

Tags: php, ini

Let me first say that in my searching today for this on stackoverflow, I came across that `mail()` should not be used for a variety of reasons and I will research the different mail libraries (if you could recommend one from the many I've seen mentioned, that would be great as well).

My company uses a simple mail() function to deliver mail during a feedback process. We use it in two different forms, `mail('to', 'subject', 'message')` and `mail('to', 'subject', 'message', 'header')`.

Since today began, mail has been very spotty when sending and had a period of a few hours where it would not send at all. I made a test page and entered a few `echo` checkpoints. Everything goes through fine as normal on my end and I verified `mail()` to be `1`. I know mail() doesn't actually SEND the mail, but rather delivers the parameters in the function to a mail-server that will send off the email. My searches on stackoverflow mentioned the php5.ini file which I located using `php.info()` and discovered that because we use a GoDaddy server, it is inaccessible through FTP to me.

I believe I'm correct in the assumption that the problem is not specifically `mail()`, but what is happening after that function executes. I would really like to see email logs but from what I read, I need access to the `ini` file to make that happen. Surely there must be another method of getting this information though.

**EDIT:** I changed the topic question to better suit what my last paragraph was aiming towards.

Comment: I would recommend using mandrillapp or something of sorts to handle mail. Mail() is unreliable to say the least..

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev based on the situation I've described as a whole right now, do you think the current issue could be stemming from the mail() function or no?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You shouldn't be using mail anyways. There is not a single advantage.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev oh I get that. As I said in the very first sentence in the topic, I will certainly be looking into using a different option. It was sheer curiosity though if this problem was more likely due to mail() or not.

Comment: Mail gave me so many headaches at some point I stopped troubleshooting anything and just started using external services since they are always more reliable. Mail function is the issue? Probably not. In itself it should work fine. The issue is most likely in something it uses and assumes to be infallible. Honestly it sounded like the mail server itself had issues but you might never know. Using mandrill for example and not even bothering with libraries will help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server uses a PHP version greater than 5.3.0, you can set the mail function log path :

`ini_set('mail.log', $logfile_path);`

Or you can use a library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Our server uses PHP Version 5.3.24.
So right now, even though I can't view php5.ini, I assume there are logs that are created. If I use mail.log to set a file path, does it CHANGE the location of the log, or does it DUPLICATE the log to an additional location? I'm not sure if by changing it, it may screw something up or raise some flags on godaddy's end (or worse, there is an actual log being delivered to somebody in this company and all of a sudden they stop getting logs. Though I asked my superior and she knows nothing of these logs).

Comment: So you can try setting the log file path as I said.

Comment: `mail.log` is a [PHP_INI_PERDIR](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) setting, meaning it can not be set using the ini_set directive. If you want to set it manually you need a .user.ini or .htaccess file.